# Issue with Create-React-App TypeScript Template, Outputting JS Files Instead of TSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm having an issue while trying to create a new React application using the Create-React-App template with TypeScript. I followed the instructions on the official documentation (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) and used the following command:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Here's the result of the command:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

The react-scripts version you're using is not compatible with the --template option.

Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


added 995 packages in 32s

34 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Success! Created my-app-test at /home/ristirianto/belajar-react/my-app-test
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app-test
  npm start

Happy hacking!

Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects.
```

My Node version: v18.17.1
My NPM version: 9.6.7

However, after the installation process, when I checked the files in the `my-app` folder, I noticed that the files have a `.js` extension instead of the expected `.tsx` for TypeScript files. This seems to indicate that TypeScript is not properly configured.

I'm not sure if I missed any step or if there's something wrong with the setup. Is there something I'm missing or a step I should be taking to ensure that TypeScript is correctly configured when using the `--template typescript` option?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Can you double check the reproduction steps in your question? Also can you post the output the command prints in the terminal?

Comment: I edited the question: added the output of the command

Comment: I suspect you may have a local version of `create-react-app` installed that does not support the `--template` option. You can check by doing `npm list -g` or `yarn global list` depending on which package manager you used and seeing if it's installed. If that's the case, I'll write an answer.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. I uninstalled Node.js and then reinstalled it using Node Version Manager (NVM). After doing this, the problem was resolved. I suspect that the previous installation, which was done using Snap, might have been causing the issue. The new installation using NVM seems to have corrected the problem.

Comment: What's Snap? If you uninstall Node all local global packages would be uninstalled as well. So it's not because where/how you install your Node version, it's just a side effect of uninstalling Node.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue documented in this GitHub thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12253. From my understanding of the discussion on that page, the problem seems to be associated with Node.js installations that were done using Snap

Comment: Ah, interesting. Do write an answer to your own question (and maybe edit your question to include your environment and original installation) so that it may help others in the future as [comments are temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

> ```
> The react-scripts version you're using is not compatible with the --template option.
> ```

The `create-react-app` version you're using doesn't support the `--template` option. As a result `--template typescript` has no effect and no `.tsx` files are generated in your project.

As to why `npx create-react-app` is not using a version that supports `--template`, I suspect you have an old version of `create-react-app` globally installed locally. I suspect this because:

1. `npx` can run packages installed locally (not just remote packages):

   > This command allows you to run an arbitrary command from an npm package (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely)

   – [`npx` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx)
2. `npx` will prompt for permission to install remote packages however your output doesn't show this prompt. The prompt looks like this:

   ```
   Need to install the following packages:
     create-react-app@x.y.z
   Ok to proceed? (y)
   ```

You can verify the above by checking globally installed packages:

- npm: `npm list -g`
- Yarn: `yarn global list`

## Solution

After you've verified that you had a globally installed `create-react-app` you can uninstall it:

- npm: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
- Yarn: `yarn global remove create-react-app`

`create-react-app` also recommends that you do not have a globally installed version:

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally [...], we recommend you uninstall the package [...] to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

– [Getting Started: Quickstart, Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue that was documented in this GitHub thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12253. Based on my understanding of the discussion on that page, the problem appears to be related to Node.js installations done using the Snap package manager. In my case, I had previously installed Node.js using Snap.

To resolve the issue, I took the following steps:

1. Uninstall Node.js: I uninstalled the existing Node.js installation.
2. Install NVM: I installed Node Version Manager (NVM) by following the instructions provided here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.
3. Install Node.js via NVM: Once NVM was installed, I used the command
   `nvm install 20` to install Node.js version 20.
4. After installing Node.js via NVM, I used the standard create-react-app command with the TypeScript template to create my app: `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`.

By taking these steps, I was able to successfully create a new React app without encountering the issue I had previously faced. This solution might be helpful for others who have experienced a similar problem after installing Node.js via Snap.